# How to restrict access to a specific wireless network to only 1 user profile in Windows 7.

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, user-profiles

Hi all,

I'm using Win7 SP1.

I've got multiple users on the laptop that can / must connect to a wireless network, lets call it Wireless1.

I've got an second wireless network, (lets call it Wireless2), which I want to limit access to only the admin user of the laptop.

Now I can remove Wireless2 in the network manager every time, but i want a more user friendly solution, so that only the admin can connect to Wireless2, and all the other users cannot ( they may see the network, but must enter the password, like all other networks ).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you're restricting access at the wrong level.  Consumer WiFi security solutions were not designed for access control for specific users.  I would suggest securing the resources on your network instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, [you can restrict wireless network connections to user profiles in Windows 7](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43782/how-to-enable-user-specific-wireless-networks-in-windows-7/). Follow these steps:

> 1)  First thing you’ll need to do is head to Network and Sharing
>   Center, which can be access through the tray icon... Once you’re there, click on Manage Wireless Networks. Once
>   there, click on the Profile types button.
>
> 2) And now you can choose the “Use all-user and per-user profiles”
>   option.

[image]

> 3) At this point, your system can now use per-user profiles—but any
>   current profiles are still set to all-user. **Keep reading...**
>
> 4) The simplest way to either create a new user-specific wireless
>   connection would be to just connect to a network—the default is per
>   user now. If you want to convert the current one, you’ll need to first
>   remove it. Just select it in the list on the Manage Wireless Networks
>   screen, and then click the Remove button.
>
> 5) Now you can use the system tray wireless icon to pick a network,
>   connect to it, and then enter the password.
>
> 6) If you right-click on the entry in the list and choose Properties,
>   you’ll see that the “Network availability” option is now set to **“Me
>   only”. Success!** The same thing will happen for any network you connect
>   to.